# Has anyone seen Galactus laughing?

Tags: marvel, galactus

The [Devourer of Worlds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galactus) is well known for his [omnipotence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galactus#Powers_and_abilities) and is regularly seen in matters of greatest import in the Marvel Universe.
But has Galactus ever been depicted laughing?

Comment: Galactus is no closer to being omnipotent than Captain America.

Comment: That's an amazing comment, Any sources to back it up?

Comment: if Galactus is not omnipotent (and there's plenty of evidence for that) then he's literally infinitely weaker than a true omnipotent. In that sense, even though Galactus is much more powerful than Captain America, he is no closer to omnipotence (infinite power).

Comment: That is without a doubt the nuttiest piece of logic I've ever heard. Please find an instance where _any_ of this is true instead of speculation.

Comment: There's nothing "nutty" about it. Maybe it doesn't hold in the fictional comics universe, but in reality, it should. The number 1 is much smaller than a billion billion, but a billion billion isn't closer to infinity than 1: all finite numbers are equidistant from infinity. And if you think that my assertion that Galactus isn't omnipotent is "nutty," then that's silly. Galactus has been defeated before.

Comment: Perhaps you didn't notice but this is the _scifi_.stackexchange.com, almost _nothing_ said here has _anything_ to do with reality.

Comment: If Galatcus laughs, but there’s no-one around to hear it because he devoured all the worlds, was the Silver Surfer’s joke really funny?

Comment: @HamSandwich is speaking mathematically. Infinity - 1 = Infinity, Infinity - 1,000,000 = Infinity. Note: this may not hold as true with, say, Infinity Stones/Gems.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Yes**
At least once:
Hercules caused him to laugh in [Hercules #4](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=9&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiTy5ul2r7JAhUEyT4KHYpUBNYQFgg1MAg&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.comicvine.com%2Fhercules%2F4050-3139%2F&usg=AFQjCNFMv1adIAMXjBYUvciIMBHg_YErgw&bvm=bv.108538919,d.eWE) (December 1982)

[image]
[image]

> In Hercules #3 and #4, the title character saves a planet called Ciegrim 7, which is known throughout the galaxy for its distilling of the finest brews, from a group of aliens called the Brotherhood.
>
> The Brotherhood are a race of aliens whose home planet was destroyed centuries ago by Galactus – an event they took as God punishing them for their sins, and from that point on, every year the survivors kidnap a planet and leave it at predesignated coordinate as a sacrifice to their vengeful God (Galactus).
> After fighting off the Brotherhood and saving Ciegram 7, Hercules is celebrated by its inhabitants as a hero, and they reward him with some of their finest ales, including a flask of “the most potent liquor in the known universe”.
>
> When Galactus discovering that his sacrifice will not be arriving this year, he heads out to find his own next meal – which turns out to be Ciegram 7. After a short battle, Hercules invites Galactus to join him for a drink – where he he spikes the world eater’s cup with the super potent liquor he received from the Ciegrams.
> It turns out Galactus knew that Hercules has spiked his drink, but drank it just to humor the young God and had himself a good laugh. To show Hercules his gratitude for the entertainment, Galactus spares Ciegram 7 and charts a course for another Galaxy.

[Source](http://whencallsgalactus.com/2011/12/02/hercules-prince-of-power-3-4-1982/)

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Another example of Galactus laughing (at Thanos's expense, no less) can be found in *The Unbeatable Squirrel Girl* #4 (2015)

[image: Galactus laughing with Squirrel Girl]

Answer (score 2):

Galactus is quite amused by Doctor Strange's feeble attempts to kill him in [*Doctor Strange* #13 (2018)](https://www.marvel.com/comics/issue/71089/doctor_strange_2018_13).

> [image]
> <sub><sup>"*Galactus Laughs*"</sup></sub>

---

And quite amused by Norrin Rad's feeeble attempts to kill him in *[The Silver Surfer](https://marvelanimated.fandom.com/wiki/Episode:The_Origin_of_the_Silver_Surfer,_Part_One)*

> 

Comment: All this guy does is chuckle, sheesh.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - He's practically giddy as a schoolgirl